# HTML Template does`t load according to page URL.why is that?

Tags: javascript, css, html, laravel

This is my normal `UI` for show details. `URL` for this is **http://127.0.0.1:8000/userregister**

[image]

But, if I press See Here Button it moves into new view which extend all the `CSS` and `JS` functions used above view. So that, new view looks like this.

Here is new `URL` :  **http://127.0.0.1:8000/Seedetails/MOB/TR/1743**

[image]

This not for this case all the other cases like this. Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: did you check network calls in browser and check for required css is loaded or not?

Comment: fiddle perhaps? are all the css files loading correctly?

Comment: user asset() method to link your css or js files ..

Comment: check the console, your css and js may not be loaded, try to add '/' in your all assets path

Comment: @Dinesh Can you please say me how to check that?

Comment: @MortezaNegahi Can you please say me that how to use that>

Comment: in browser developer-tools of press f12 and click on network and refresh

Comment: @Dinesh their No JS but in Css there is a one file util.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Training Management</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Free Bootstrap Theme by BootstrapMade.com">
    <meta name="keywords"
          content="free website templates, free bootstrap themes, free template, free bootstrap, free website template">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Raleway:300,400,900,700italic,700,300,600">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/jquery.bxslider.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/animate.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}"/>
    {!! Charts::assets() !!}

</head>
<body>

<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="myDiv">
    <!--HEADER-->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="bg-color">
            <header id="main-header">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home#">MOB<span class="logo-dec">ITEL</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                                <li class=""><a href="#feature">Trainee Details</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#service">User Registration</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#portfolio">Downloads</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#testimonial">Certificate & Evaluation</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#blog">Training Programs</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>

                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                                           aria-expanded="false">
                                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>

                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                                    Logout
                                                </a>

                                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"
                                                      style="display: none;">
                                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                                </form>


                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>


            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="banner-info text-center wow fadeIn delay-05s">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            @yield('content')

        </div>


        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <p>&copy; All Rights Reserved.</p>
                    <div class="credits">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>


</div>


<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.easing.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/wow.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.bxslider.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('contactform/contactform.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Your css and js files are not included in the page.you can include it in this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

lets create js directory in the laravel's app/public folder. There you have to put `jquery.js` file. The function `asset()` produces the necessary url for you.

Same procedure for the css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i dont understand function asset() produces the necessary url for you.can u please explain bit?

Comment: according to your way css loaded.but js not get loaded

Comment: 1)`asset()` function produces path for loading css,js.
2) if js not loaded, then try  `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('js/jquery.js') }}">`</script>, `url()` returns base url. and make sure your jquery.js file is in **project_folder/public/js** directory.